# MOQ Simple Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm a new baby in MOQ and TDD, i just have couple of questions on how to write test cases on my following method.

```
public Int DevideBy(int num1, int num2)
{
      // Some third party call that needs to be mocked
      return num1 / num2;
}
```

I wanted to see a positive test cases and a negative where it throws exception. Please provide samples. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a class that would require mocks.

Typically you want to use mocks when there are dependencies.  For example, when your class relies on a database class, or some kind of remote service.

You would use Moq to instantiate a mocked version of the dependency and inject it into the class under test, and set up the way it would respond to any methods called on it.

For your example above, simple unit tests will suffice.

Using the xUnit framework, here is an example of a negative case:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldThrowExceptionOnDivideByZero
{
   var x = new MyClass();
   Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => x.DevideBy(10, 0));
}
```